# How do I call a component's method from another component if they're in different modules?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a `MenuComponent` inside a module called `menu` and I want to call  the `getMenu(path:string)` method of this component in the `AppComponent` which is in another module.

This is my `MenuComponent`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
TreeComponent,
TreeNode,
} from 'angular-tree-component';
import { MenuService } from '../../menu.service';

@Component({
selector: 'menu',
templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./menu.component.css']
})
export class MenuComponent {

constructor(private menuService: MenuService) { }

nodes:any;

 getMenu(path:string): void {
   this.menuService.getData(path).subscribe(data => {
         // Read the result field from the JSON response.

         let newValue = JSON.stringify(data).replace('{"Node":', '[');
         newValue = newValue.substring(0,newValue.length - 1);
         newValue+="]";
        const menu=JSON.parse(newValue);
         this.nodes = menu;
      });

 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the module, and call the method - static and instance versions shown below... in your case it is an instance method, so the second example should work.

```
import { MenuComponent } from './menu';

// Static
MenuComponent.getMenu('...');

// or Instance
const menu = new MenuCompnent(myMenuService);
menu.getMenu('...');
```

You'll need to inject a menu service. You can import the module and construct one of those in the same way.

Check out the [Angular component interaction docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding) to see how to do this "The Angular Way". There are multiple neat patterns for interacting between two components.